# Dynamic LinearLayout + Touch Event always use the last LinearLayout added

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I'm tying to add a list of dynamic "buttons" to a Layout. right now my buttons consist of a LinearLayout, ImageView and TextView. I add a touch even to the LinearLayout on each iteration. All objects are added and display correctly. But everything goes wrong from there.

The touch event will fire for each button, but the corresponding sender object is the last LinearLayout added.

For example: I have 3 "buttons" to add. Each are created and added to where they need to be. In the loop I add an event handler to the Touch event for each "button". When I go to touch the first one, the last one highlights. I touch the second one, the last one highlights.

I am using a common method for the touch event and identifying them apart by a secondary value I store (like a tag).

Provide below is the relevant code to this situation.

Code for adding the "buttons" based on a record set from a web service.

```
if (calendars != null && calendars.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    LinearLayout buttonCalendar = null;
    TextView labelTitle = null;
    ImageView imageIcon = null;

    Int64 App_CalendarID = 0;
    String Title = "";

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.DpToPx(45, this.View.Context));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Android.DpToPx(45, this.View.Context), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelParams =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

    Drawable icon = null;

    icon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.image_calendar_light);

    TransitionDrawable buttonTransition = 
        (TransitionDrawable)Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.button_transition);

    foreach (DataRow row in calendars.Rows)
    {
        App_CalendarID = Convert.ToInt64(row["App_CalendarID"]);
        Title = Convert.ToString(row["Title"]);

        buttonCalendar = new LinearLayout(layoutFeatureBody.Context)
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            LayoutParameters = layoutParams,
            Background = buttonTransition,
            Id = (Int32)App_CalendarID,
        };

        imageIcon = new ImageView(layoutFeatureBody.Context)
        {
            Background = icon,
            LayoutParameters = imageParams,
        };
        imageIcon.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside);

        buttonCalendar.AddView(imageIcon);

        labelTitle = new TextView(layoutFeatureBody.Context)
        {
            Text = Title,
            TextSize = 14f,
            LayoutParameters = labelParams,
            Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical,
        };
        labelTitle.SetTextColor(Color.White);

        buttonCalendar.AddView(labelTitle);

        layoutFeatureBody.AddView(buttonCalendar);

        buttonCalendar.Touch += buttonCalendar_Touch;
    }
}
```

Below is the method assigned for the Touch event.

```
void buttonCalendar_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    LinearLayout buttonLayout = (LinearLayout)sender;

    Android.TransitionButton(ref buttonLayout, e.Event);

    if (e.Event.Action != MotionEventActions.Up)
        return;

}
```

My guess events don't work the same as they do in .Net :-X I'm struggling finding any relevant help to this exact situation online already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what I did (no code changed, just moved). But I did some long overdue work Ie moved all relevant code to a subclass of LinearLayout to represent my "button".

Really just makes the code easier to read and more manageable.

Seems now the events operate independently. Here is my updated code, maybe someone can help explain what I'm witnessing here.

Code below adds the buttons :

```
if (calendars != null && calendars.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ButtonEx buttonCalendar = null;

    Int64 App_CalendarID = 0;
    String Title = "";

    Drawable icon = null;

    icon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.image_calendar_light);

    foreach (DataRow row in calendars.Rows)
    {
        App_CalendarID = Convert.ToInt64(row["App_CalendarID"]);
        Title = Convert.ToString(row["Title"]);

        buttonCalendar = new ButtonEx(layoutFeatureBody.Context)
        {
            Text = Title,
            Tag = App_CalendarID,
            Image = icon,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            TextSize = 14,
        };

        layoutFeatureBody.AddView(buttonCalendar);

        buttonCalendar.Touch += buttonCalendar_Touch;
    }
}
```

Below is my button class :

```
public class ButtonEx : LinearLayout
{

    ImageView imageView = null;

    TextView textView = null;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = null;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelParams = null;

    public new Object Tag
    { get; set; }

    private String _Text = "";

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (textView != null)
                textView.Text = value;
            _Text = value;
        }
    }

    private Color _TextColor = Color.White;

    public Color TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (textView != null)
                textView.SetTextColor(value);
            _TextColor = value;
        }
    }

    private float _TextSize = 12f;

    public float TextSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _TextSize;
        }
        set
        {
            if (textView != null)
                textView.TextSize = value;
            _TextSize = value;
        }
    }

    public Drawable _Image = null;

    public Drawable Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _Image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (imageView != null)
                imageView.Background = value;
            _Image = value;
        }
    }

    public ButtonEx(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        TransitionDrawable buttonTransition =
            (TransitionDrawable)Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.button_transition);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.DpToPx(45, context));

        this.Background = buttonTransition;
        this.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        imageParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                Android.DpToPx(45, context), 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        labelParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        imageView = new ImageView(context)
        {
            LayoutParameters = imageParams,
        };
        imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside);

        this.AddView(imageView);

        textView = new TextView(context)
        {
            LayoutParameters = labelParams,
            Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical,
        };

        this.AddView(textView);

    }

}
```